# OpenGL vertex buffer objects and ordering of textured vs non-textured geometry

Tags: opengl

I am rendering 2 sets of geometry using vertex buffer objects in OpenGL - one with textures and one without. I am not using the programmable pipeline because of legacy code.

What I find is that if I render the textured geometry first followed by the non-textured geometry, everything looks good. But if I do the reverse, the textured geometry is not drawn.

I am using interleaved arrays, and here is the rendering code:

```
void MyClass::render()
{

    // 3*v + 3*c + 3*n + (2*t)
    const char *base = NULL;
    GLsizei stride = _enableTexture ? 11*sizeof(GLfloat) : 9*sizeof(GLfloat);
    GLvoid* vOffset = (GLvoid*)0;
    GLvoid* cOffset = (GLvoid*)(3*sizeof(GLfloat));
    GLvoid* nOffset = (GLvoid*)(6*sizeof(GLfloat));
    GLvoid* tOffset = (GLvoid*)(9*sizeof(GLfloat));

    // prepare vertex VBO
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _iBuffer);

    // enable vertex array
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, stride, vOffset);

    // enable color array
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, stride, cOffset);

    // enable normal array
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, stride, nOffset);

    // texture coords
    if(_enableTexture) {    
      // enable texture array
      glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
      glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, stride, tOffset);
    }

    // draw geometry
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, _nVertices);      

    // disable/unbind
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    if(_enableTexture) {
      glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    }

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

This works:

```
myClassTextured->render();
myClassNonTextured->render();
```

This fails:

```
myClassNonTextured->render();
myClassTextured->render();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a good old *"OpenGL is a state machine"*-problem.

Comment: Where in your code do you bind the texture itself? I would bet that it is bound before the calls, and then it is unbound after the first render and not bound again. (or maybe another OpenGL state is turned on/off on a similar fashion.)

Comment: Please show the rest of your code. Especially enabling and binding the texture, calling `MyClass::render` and everything the like. Of course your `render` function doesn't tell anyone anything as it doesn't do anything related to texturing.

Comment: @TalDarom & Christian Rau: I don't think it's a bin/unbind issue, as I am doing it, and also the entire textured geometry is missing - not just the texture itself. I also think it's a state machine issue, but I am finding it difficult to post the whole code as it is a big application and these things are spread about.

Comment: @M-V: If your code is too big to post, then you need to find a way to make it smaller. Your problem is due to the interaction of various systems; we cannot magically know what that problem is without seeing those systems. If you can't make it smaller, then you're going to have to debug it yourself.

Comment: @M-V In order to make sure its not an OpenGL state issue try to get and print all the OpenGL states you change somewhere in your code. A good practice when using OpenGL state machine is to have a function that sets all required states before each render and never assume that an internal OpenGL state is in the correct state.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to check:

First, if `_enableTexture` is false you should disable `GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY` in `render()`. And as pointed out by *Tal* and *Christian* already, why aren't you enabling/disabling `GL_TEXTURE_2D` in `render()` as well? Much easier to understand and debug.

Second, how are you allocating `_iBuffer` and can `_enableTexture` change afterwards? As written, your `render()` method only works if `_iBuffer` is allocated with 9 floats per vert if `_enableTexture` is false, 11 if true. But if you allocate `_iBuffer` with enough space for texture coords whether you actually end up using them or not, the stride value should always be 11.

Comment: +1 for the points about the stride. Sounds like a good guess.